# How can I wrap text around an image in the bottom right of its container?

Tags: css

I want to place my link button in the bottom right corner of its containing div and have the text wrap around it. The only way I can think is to use the code below (absolute positioning) and put break tags in my paragraph to force the text not to overlap the image button. Is there CSS that can acheive the same without needing to use the break tags in the HTML? The word 'aliqua' should drop onto the next line (below).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#teaser-cell { 
  float: left;
  width: 164px;
  height: 164px;
}
#teaser-cell .link-button {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 129px;
  background: url(sprite.png) 70px;
}

<div id="teaser-cell">
  <span>Teaser 1</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <a class="link-button" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, no if you use the image as a background... You can create a div with the size you want and place the `img`, `a` and `p` tags inside your div. Then you can position the image inside the div and make the text wrap around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/A26bG/:

```
#teaser-cell {
  width: 180px;
}

#teaser-cell .link-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(...) 70px;
  float: right;
}

<div id="teaser-cell">
  <span>Teaser 1</span>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <a class="link-button" href="#"></a>
    </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image will not stick to the bottom right of the container with your CSS.

Comment: Does `teaser-cell` have a pre-defined height or is it based on content size?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, teaser-cell has a fixed width of 164px by 164px. The orange button is part of a sprite (35px by 140px) which is positioned in a 35px by 35px block.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/A26bG/2/. If you can wrap the last word into `<span>` with `padding-right`, then it is good.

Comment: Sorry, but all the text has to be in between just a single <p> tag. The simplist solution is to put <br /> tags in to force line breaks, but not very elegant.